# Auto Email when specific conditions in google sheet met

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, datatrigger, eventtrigger

I work in tender admin and am currently working on a sheet that lists all of our open tenders, their due dates, and the tender status (Pending review, to be submitted' etc).

I am trying to set up an Automatic email whenever a new tender is added to the spreadsheet or if there is a change in the due date or status column.

Currently I have the below code and have set up an On Edit Trigger. The problem is that with this code, an email notification is sent whenever there is a change to any cell within the range, so when I am entering a new tender to the sheet a new email notification is triggered as I update each cell within the row, rather than once the whole row is updated.

Does anybody have any ideas how I could update this code? I am very very new to this.

Ive also included an image of the table within the sheet.

```
//@OnlyCurrentDoc
function processEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rows = sheet.getRangeByName("tendersopen").getValues();
  var headerRow = rows.shift();
  var editedRow = e.range.getRow();
  
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Template");
  template.headerRow = headerRow;
  template.editedRow = editedRow;
  template.rows = rows;
  
  var html = template.evaluate().getContent();
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "email@gmail.com",
    subject: "Tenders sheet updated",
    htmlBody: html
  });
}
```

[Google Sheet Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgJcT.png)

[image]

Thanks so much,
Michelle

I tried to add an if statement to see if I could just get the email to send if the Action column was updated, but this stopped all email notifications coming through.

Comment: Which column is status?

Comment: Hi Cooper, It is column G - Action

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function processEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const col = [4, 7];//Changing these should get new rows
  const idx = col.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
  if (sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && ~idx) {
    let t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Template");
    t.headerRow = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    t.editedRow = sh.getRange(e.range.startRow, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    t.rows = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var html = t.evaluate().getContent();
    MailApp.sendEmail({ to: "email@gmail.com", subject: "Tenders sheet updated", htmlBody: html });
  }
}
```

This is similar and it only accesses the `if` when column 4 and 7 are edited

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const col = [4, 7];//Changing these should get new rows
  const idx = col.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && ~idx) {
    e.source.toast("Gate1");
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it is the same as before ... I still get a notification whenever there is any change to a cell?

Comment: I can't test it since you did not supply the template

Comment: I ended up getting the following code to work sort of:

Comment: I am not sure how to do that? I did end up getting some code to work but had to make some changes to the actual spreadsheet. I tired to add the code but exceeded the characters of the comment

Comment: Post code in question